# Moderator elections - candidate threads

Tags: discussion, election

The [election page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election) suggests that nomination introductions be editable throughout the nomination phase, and encourages comments and edits which apparently should address these comments. However, it only allows 1200 chars for this discussion to go on - which I think is not very effective. However, [the elections announcement](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/2012-community-moderator-election) says that questions to candidates should be asked here on Meta. So I suggest that each candidate feel free to open a thread herea. The intro on the nominations page should contain a link to the discussion on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would be productive to fragment the discussion between the nomination stumps, Meta and the Town Hall chat, where all candidates will have the chance to expand on their opinions on moderation. Voters should feel free to ask Meta questions addressed to all candidates, especially if they can't make it to the Town Hall chat, but I don't think using Meta to expand on nomination stumps would be particularly helpful.

Ideally the short stumps should encourage voters to go through the candidates' profiles and see what each candidate have been doing so far. You could expand your stump a bit to include links to what you personally think are the high points of your participation, focusing on activities that relate to moderation, such as relevant badges and specific Meta posts.

I think that the statistics on [Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) and the Town Hall chat will give us a far better idea on which candidates are suitable for the role, than the nomination stumps. My own stump on the [recent Programmers election](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/2) was excruciatingly long, in retrospect it was more noise than signal. Although I still have absolutely no idea why people voted for me, I don't think it had anything to do with reading a babbling wall of text.

Comment: And now it's easier to understand why there's a 1200 character limit :P

Comment: OK, thanks Yannis!